# Dropdown submenu only fades after the second rollover, but not the first time through

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I'm trying to incorporate a multiple level drop-down menu into my website via jQuery whose submenus fade in and out with alternating hover states. Everything works fine after the second mouseover, but for some reason the function doesn't seem to fire the first time the menu is hovered over.Has anyone encountered such a problem?
I saw a similar question that had no replies or code examples so I figured I would post my code.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(function(){   
            $('li').has('ul').hover(
                function(){
                    $(this).children('ul').stop().animate(
                        {
                            opacity:1
                        }
                    );//end animate
                },

                function(){
                    $(this).children('ul').stop().animate(
                        {
                            opacity:0
                        }
                    );//end animate
                });

                $(this).prepend('<div id="trigger"></div>');    
        });
```

I have a selector in my CSS (called #trigger) that has its opacity set to 0, which acts as 
the call to action for the functions to fire. Thanks in advance, querystring.

Comment: Can you prepare a jsfiddle for it?

Comment: @Kundan Singh Chouhan - Here is my fiddle for it:[http://jsfiddle.net/vsZDu/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/vsZDu/4/)

Comment: I guess everything works fine in fiddle

Comment: Actually, if you'll watch for it the first time you hover over the main menu UL, you'll notice the fade-in doesn't work until the second time hovering over each item, or at-least that's what's happening on my machine.

Comment: Well its working in first time as well which browser you are using?

Comment: Firefox 16.0.2, and yourself?